# Анимация процесса

Tags: ios, objective-c, процесс

Использую этот код, чтобы загружать файл и видеть процесс.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Chapter1.mp3"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSString *stringURL = @"https://getfile.dokpub.com/yandex/get/https://yadi.sk/d/TfsCShdksCNR";
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        float progress = [urlData length]/(float)[urlData length];
        [self.mainView.progressView setProgress:progress];

    });
```

Проблема в том, что анимация появляется в последнюю секунду загрузки. Что нужно сделать, чтобы анимация осуществлялась в течение всего процесса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] не возвращает прогресс. Он завершится только по завершению закачки. Кроме того он затормаживает текущий процесс, поэтому его не стоит дергать из главного потока (там где одновляется UI).

Для получения процесса нужно использовать NSURLSession или библиотеку вроде AFNetworking. Ну или поставить UIActivityIndicator, он хоть как-то пользователя проинформирует.

Answer (score 2):

У вас блок выполнится линейно - в urldata попадает файл с ссылки, затем вы записываете его в папку, только после чего вы выставляете прогресс. Лучше используйте NSURLSession для загрузки больших файлов.  Отслеживать ход загрузки можно будет в методе

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
```

Мануал [на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209736/)